# How to dynamically access the String tokens(Graph values) in the below code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

It is turning out to be pain, I have already parsed required JSON objects and converted them to array but finding hard to generate string tokens as required as the parameters in the function.

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                 **"X,Y\n" +"2015-08-07 05:01:15 ,0\n" + "2015-08-07 05:01:15,-0.4\n" +  "2015-08-07 05:01:15,-0.54\n" + "2015-08-06 05:04:15,0.65\n" +  "2015-08-08 05:01:21,-1\n" + "2015-08-01 05:06:15,0.0\n" + "2015-08-03 05:01:15,-0.1\n" + "2015-08-04 05:04:42,1\n"**,
{
     legend: 'always',
     animatedZooms: true,
     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above question was to create a JSON file and load the file dynamically. Used D3 instead of Dygraph.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
         var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
         xobj.open('GET', 'js/data/xxxx', true); 
         xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 };
```